# seasonal decomposition loess daily temperature time series

Tags: r, forecasting, decomposition

I have a 10 year daily time series of air temperatures:

```
x <- c(rep((seq(-3,5,by=0.85)),365),NA)
```

I converted it to a time series object like this:

```
x <- ts(x, frequency=10, start=1)
```

and ran stlm

```
stlm(x, s.window=365, robust=TRUE, allow.multiplicative.trend=TRUE, level=0.95)
```

which produced the error

```
error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
```

This is very strange, because meteorological time series are highly seasonal. What could I do to fix that? Is there a problem with the zeros?

Any help appreciated.
UPDATE: There was one missing value in my time series, which produced the error. The partial code

```
robust=TRUE, allow.multiplicative.trend=TRUE, level=0.95
```

produced another error and the arguments obviously cannot be used.

How can I decompose my time series adequately into season and trend in order to identify the trend which eventually changed during the 10 years?

Comment: I get `Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  unused argument (level = 0.95)`, and when I remove the `level` argument, I get good results.  So this is not currently reproducible

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: *produced another error*.... so what's the new error? Error messages are often very informative (your first one sure was!). Have you tried leaving out your missing value?

Comment: Yes I did. But then the error occured that the code contains unused arguments. It said: error in etsmodel(y, errortype  [i], trendtype  [j], seasontype  [k], damped  [l]: unused argument  (allow.multiplicative.trend = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using the dsa package, which is explicitly designed to handle daily data. You have to convert your data first to xts, but then, you'll be fine,

```
library(dsa); library(xts)
x <- c(rep((seq(-3,5,by=0.85)),365),NA) # I didn't change these strange  looking data ;-)

# Converting to xts
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),length=length(x),by="days")
x <- xts(x, order.by=dates)

result <- dsa(x, fourier_number=24) # if no monthly recurring cycle is visible
                                    # fourier_number can be reduced or left empty.

sa <- result$output[,1]             # This is the seasonally adjusted series
xtsplot(result$output[,c(2,1)], names=c("original series", "seasonally adjusted series"))
```